# how to make xcodebuild ignore errors

Tags: xcode, makefile, xcodebuild, iwyu

I want to use [include-what-you-use](https://code.google.com/p/include-what-you-use/) with xcodebuild. The problem is when I do:

```
$ export CC=/path/to/include-what-you-use
$ xcodebuild
```

from command line, I get errors and build stops. I've read that a common way to use iwyu with `make` is to run `make -k`, so I want to use `xcodebuild` in a similar way. Is it possible? I found nothing about it in `man xcodebuild`.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to find a simple solution. I've written a wrapper script around include-what-you-use:

```
#!/bin/sh
/path-to-iwyu/include-what-you-use "$@"
exit 0
```

It is not a very good solution, but it works.. Please tell me if you know a better way.